# Android Studio Git Local Changes: Difference Between Rollback & Delete

Tags: android-studio, rollback

In Android Studio, Git Local Changes window, what is the difference between 'Rollback' & 'Delete' ?

[image]

Comment: Well, as the names suggest: "rollback" will undo changes to reestablish a previous state of he file and "delete" will remove the file completely.

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for replying, by delete do you mean from the 'local changes' changeset or entirely from project?

Comment: Why you don't just try?

Comment: Don't want to mess up production codebase and don't have a sample project handy on the current machine, that's why I'm asking here :)